# Generic type parameters bounds and concrete class

Tags: java, generics, scjp

From page 49 of OCP Java SE 6 Programmer Practice Exams, question 11. We are given such code:

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }
public class Carpet<V extends B> {
    public <X extends V> Carpet<? extends V> method(Carpet<? super X> e) {
        // insert code here
    }
}
```

And we are asked: *Which, inserted independently at marked line, will compile?*

So, I'm testing the first answer - `return new Carpet<X>()`. It works. Ok, my reasoning goes like well, if I have a return type of `Carpet<? extends V>`, it must return something that extends `V`. Just before it's written, that `X extends V`, so that's perfect, `X` works.

Next answer - `return new Carpet<V>()`. Well, this is even simpler, because `V` already "extends" `V`, so I can return that. It works, ok, good.

Next - `return new Carpet<A>()`. This is not working, compiler is shouting:

```
Type parameter 'A' is not within its bound; should extend 'B'
```

But, I agree. It's written near the class declaration, `V extends B`. So, I understand I can return something that extends `V`, which extends `B`. For sure not `A`.

So, I see the next answer - `return new Carpet<B>()`. Phew, easy, the compiler just said "should extend `B`, so `B` (like before `V` for "something that extends `V`") should be just perfect. But! It's not compiling:

```
Error:(6, 16) java: incompatible types
  required: Carpet<? extends V>
  found:    Carpet<B>
```

I don't understand why. Explanation given in book is:

> It's illegal to use a concrete class type since the exact scope of V
>   is unknown.

But frankly, I still don't get it. I'm not sure what the "exact scope" in that context means, but the compiler said, that return type parameter should extend `B`. So, he is able to figure it out (like me) that "something that extends `V`" is "something that extends `B`". So, why `B` is not working?

Could you please provide better explanation?

Comment: You gave me an headache

Comment: @Dici Hah, sorry, that wasn't my intention. Good that not [this](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/f2/f260bfabd8c3367fa895b7d2e2908c8f2407c7f3c21e6292087dc325d5713b83.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V is the generic type of Carpet. When instantiating a Carpet, the user of the class chooses the concrete type of V. It could be B, or C, or any other class that extends B directly or indirectly:

```
Carpet<B> carpetOfB = new Carpet<B>();
```

or

```
Carpet<C> carpetOfC = new Carpet<C>();
```

or

```
Carpet<Plane> carpetOfPlane = new Carpet<Plane>();
```

Whatever the user chooses as concrete type for V (let's say he chooses Plane, which extends C), the method must return a Carpet of a type that extends V. So, in this case, this type must be Plane or a subtype of Plane. And clearly, B doesn't qualify, since it doesn't extend Plane.

Comment: +1 Seems logical when you say it ! There's a typo however (Pnale instead of Plane). I let you fix it.

Comment: +1 I had to read that several times, but finally got it, thank you a lot! :) So, the returned type must be "flexible" (must be of a type which user of the class gave), not "hard-coded"... makes sense now :)